# Factory Design Pattern in PHP, Is this correct?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm reading about Design Patterns in PHP, and, I'm skeptical of the code which I'd written to implement the Factory Design Pattern.

Does this code implement **REAL** Factory Design?

And, Do I need to use any interface here?

The code is:

```
class DBFactory 
{
   const MYSQL      =   1;
   const ORACLE     =   2;
   const SQLITE     =   3;

   private $objectTxt = null;

   function __construct($type) 
   {
       if ($type == self::MYSQL) {
           $this->objectTxt = 'MySQL Object'; 
           return ; //MySQL Object
       }

       else if ($type == self::ORACLE) 
       {
           $this->objectTxt = 'Oracle Object';
           return ; //Oracle Object
       }

       else if ($type == self::SQLITE)
       {
           $this->objectTxt = 'SQlite Object';
           return 'SQLite Object'; //SQLite Object           
       }
   }

   function __toString() {
        return $this->objectTxt;   
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks like an object, that implements its own factory in instance time.  Normally I'd expect to see this done with static methods, or a separate class altogether.  Look up Doctrine DBAL, thats the factory pattern.

Comment: @Flosculus does **normally** means ideal?

Comment: **normally** means **conventional**

Comment: as per my understanding, factory pattern is to decouple the dependency and return an instance as a whole ?? need some verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's implements the `Factory Design Pattern`, but, it's **much better** to use a static method, as follows:

```
public static function getInstance($type) { ... }
```

To get an instance:

```
$db = DBFactory::getInstance(DBFactory::MYSQL);
```

Comment: +1 for shoving the code from the constructor to its own method. But "it's much better to use a static method" - is not true. If you insist on that opinion, please tell why.

Comment: Thanks, @DanFromGermany, It's **better** to use static methods, because of faster instantiate. 
You just need to get an instance of an object, so, why to write more code to get an instance? It's also more readable and accessible within other classes.
Imagine that we have another class which access the Factory Class, in this case, we need to instantiate the Factory first, but, with a static method, we don't need to do that at all.

Comment: :-) There are a few things against static: Initializing dependencies. You can't do it with static calls and in big projects, you often have many dependencies. And you often need a good stacktrace which is not always possible with statics. Btw, a call to a static function does not require an instance. It can have one, if it's a singleton.